# Error While starting Zookeper -Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am unable to start Zookeper. I have tried deleting the folder and re-starting from scratch and also tried changing the directory. But I am getting the following error in the CMD:

```
D:\Zookeper & Kafka\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
'Kafka\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\bin\windows\..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'Kafka\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\bin\windows\..\..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache
```

I also tried running the Zookeper from home directory of Kafka like:

```
\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

But the same thing appears. Please help me with this. I have already installed JDK and JRE and have set the environment variables and working with Tomcat Apache and developing projects in NetBeans. But I am confused with this.

Comment: Try renaming the directory **Zookeper & Kafka** to something different without spaces

Comment: Tried it by changing the directory to "KAFKA", but I am getting the error again : "Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache"

Comment: please remove space in the folder name `Zookeper & Kafka` and try.
As you can see, I feel it's taking only  `Kafka\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\bin\windows\..`. Will add it as answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem with Java path and classpath in the Environment variables. Setting the classpath correctly solved the issue. Thank you

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain what was corrected ?

Comment: Simple, in my environment variables classpath and path is not set to JAVA , so KAFKA couldn't find the path to my JAVA. So , I just set the path to JAVA in environment variables and it fixed the issue.
Make sure you won't add the path multiple times in environmental variables. Only single time is enough